# flask + mod_wsgi + Apache 2.4 not working (windows)

Tags: python, windows, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

help me, people..
i've been working on this for 2 days.
so, i dont know why this is not working, i already follow the instruction.

**folder structure**
[image: folder structure]

**route.py**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'asdonasfbadkjdnkasjfbnkajsdnkasfnaksjdn'

@app.get('/')
def home():
    return jsonify("hello world")
```

**web.wsgi**

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'D:\\app\\Python310_Project\\FlaskStart')
from apps.route import app as application
```

**flask.conf** (already Included in httpd.conf)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin Flask
    ServerName *mylocalIP*:80
    AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi
    WSGIScriptReloading On
    WSGIScriptAlias /apps "D:/app/Python310_Project/FlaskStart/wsgi/web.wsgi"

    ErrorLog "D:/app/Python310_Project/FlaskStart/wsgi/logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "D:/app/Python310_Project/FlaskStart/wsgi/logs/access.log" combined
    LogLevel debug
    
    DocumentRoot "D:/app/Python310_Project/FlaskStart"
    <Directory "D:/app/Python310_Project/FlaskStart">
            Require all granted
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    </Directory>
    
</VirtualHost>
```

on **error.log** shown:

```
[Sun Oct 09 16:10:12.433286 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 12940:tid 1252] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 10.31.254.46:53711] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sun Oct 09 16:10:12.433286 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 12940:tid 1252] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 10.31.254.46:53711] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sun Oct 09 16:10:12.496229 2022] [wsgi:info] [pid 12940:tid 1252] [client 10.31.254.46:53711] mod_wsgi (pid=12940, process='', application='10.31.254.46|/apps'): Loading Python script file 'D:/app/Python310_Project/FlaskStart/wsgi/web.wsgi'.
[Sun Oct 09 16:10:12.748229 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 12940:tid 1252] [client 10.31.254.46:53711] mod_wsgi (pid=12940): Failed to exec Python script file 'D:/app/Python310_Project/FlaskStart/wsgi/web.wsgi'.
[Sun Oct 09 16:10:12.748229 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 12940:tid 1252] [client 10.31.254.46:53711] mod_wsgi (pid=12940): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'D:/app/Python310_Project/FlaskStart/wsgi/web.wsgi'.
[Sun Oct 09 16:10:12.750229 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 12940:tid 1252] [client 10.31.254.46:53711] Traceback (most recent call last):\r
[Sun Oct 09 16:10:12.750229 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 12940:tid 1252] [client 10.31.254.46:53711]   File "D:/app/Python310_Project/FlaskStart/wsgi/web.wsgi", line 8, in <module>\r
[Sun Oct 09 16:10:12.750229 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 12940:tid 1252] [client 10.31.254.46:53711]     from apps.route import app as application\r
[Sun Oct 09 16:10:12.750229 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 12940:tid 1252] [client 10.31.254.46:53711]   File "D:\\app\\Python310_Project\\FlaskStart\\apps\\route.py", line 4, in <module>\r
[Sun Oct 09 16:10:12.750229 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 12940:tid 1252] [client 10.31.254.46:53711]     app = Flask(__name__)\r
[Sun Oct 09 16:10:12.750229 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 12940:tid 1252] [client 10.31.254.46:53711]   File "D:\\app\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\app.py", line 709, in __init__\r
[Sun Oct 09 16:10:12.750229 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 12940:tid 1252] [client 10.31.254.46:53711]     self.add_url_rule(\r
[Sun Oct 09 16:10:12.750229 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 12940:tid 1252] [client 10.31.254.46:53711]   File "D:\\app\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\scaffold.py", line 50, in wrapper_func\r
[Sun Oct 09 16:10:12.750229 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 12940:tid 1252] [client 10.31.254.46:53711]     return f(self, *args, **kwargs)\r
[Sun Oct 09 16:10:12.750229 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 12940:tid 1252] [client 10.31.254.46:53711]   File "D:\\app\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\app.py", line 1354, in add_url_rule\r
[Sun Oct 09 16:10:12.750229 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 12940:tid 1252] [client 10.31.254.46:53711]     self.url_map.add(rule)\r
[Sun Oct 09 16:10:12.750229 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 12940:tid 1252] [client 10.31.254.46:53711]   File "D:\\app\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\werkzeug\\routing\\map.py", line 174, in add\r
[Sun Oct 09 16:10:12.750229 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 12940:tid 1252] [client 10.31.254.46:53711]     rule.bind(self)\r
[Sun Oct 09 16:10:12.750229 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 12940:tid 1252] [client 10.31.254.46:53711]   File "D:\\app\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\werkzeug\\routing\\rules.py", line 559, in bind\r
[Sun Oct 09 16:10:12.750229 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 12940:tid 1252] [client 10.31.254.46:53711]     self.compile()\r
[Sun Oct 09 16:10:12.750229 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 12940:tid 1252] [client 10.31.254.46:53711]   File "D:\\app\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\werkzeug\\routing\\rules.py", line 667, in compile\r
[Sun Oct 09 16:10:12.750229 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 12940:tid 1252] [client 10.31.254.46:53711]     RulePart(\r
[Sun Oct 09 16:10:12.750229 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 12940:tid 1252] [client 10.31.254.46:53711] TypeError: RulePart() takes no arguments\r
```

[image]

how can i make this work? 
os == windows 11 (x64) 
python == 3.10 (x64) 
mod_wsgi == 4.9.2 tried 4.9.4 not working too (x64)

Comment: any luck on this, I am also facing the same issue